# prevent the app to be displayed in ( open as dialog ) for specific keywords in url using manifest intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, deep-linking, intentfilter

Right now in my manifest code I have

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter
        android:autoVerify="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:name="default-url"
            android:host="@string/bc"
            android:scheme="@string/bc" />
    </intent-filter>
```

which allow the user to get open with dialog if he click on URL that start with domain of my application for example: [pop-up dialog to select the app](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links)

and its working fine, however, I'm facing an issue when the user request forgets password he receives a link on his email to reset his password.

the link he received is like this: [www.domain.com/forget_password/email](http://www.domain.com/forget_password/email).

what I want is to keep the app link working but if the domain contains /forget_password open the browser by default, not the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is no "exclude" logic in `<intent-filter>`. You cannot create an `<intent-filter>` that says "I accept everything except this".

You will need to handle the `forget_password` path in your app, perhaps by launching a Web browser yourself.

Comment: how do i listen to the data in url when opening the app?

Comment: @HossamHassan: I am uncertain exactly what you mean by that. The contents of the URL will be in the form of a `Uri` object. You get that by calling `getData()` on an `Intent`. You get the `Intent` that created your activity by calling `getIntent()`; if your activity was brought back to the foreground, you get the `Intent` that did that by overriding `onNewIntent()`.